# itextsharp NullReferenceException (PageRefs)

Tags: exception, pdf, itext, nullreferenceexception

I am using itextsharp 5.4.2 to open a library of pdf documents (all generated programatically using the same pdf generation tool, albeit possibly different versions of that tool). itextsharp is working fine for all the documents except one, which is throwing an exception (the document opens fine in acrobat pdf reader):

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.PageRefs.IteratePages(PRIndirectReference rpage)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.PageRefs.ReadPages()
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.PageRefs..ctor(PdfReader reader)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.ReadPages()
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.ReadPdf()
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader..ctor(Byte[] pdfIn, Byte[] ownerPassword)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader..ctor(Byte[] pdfIn)
```

I also tried to open the same document in iText RUPS 5.4.2 and got the following error while "Reading the Cross-Reference table":

```
Exception in thread "Thread-7" ExceptionConverter: com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException: Invalid object number. at file pointer 66562
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PRTokeniser.throwError(PRTokeniser.java:199)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readSingleObject(PdfReader.java:1171)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.getPdfObject(PdfReader.java:1076)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.getPdfObjectRelease(PdfReader.java:1057)
    at com.itextpdf.rups.model.IndirectObjectFactory.storeNextObject(IndirectObjectFactory.java:88)
    at com.itextpdf.rups.model.ObjectLoader.doTask(ObjectLoader.java:97)
    at com.itextpdf.rups.model.BackgroundTask$2.run(BackgroundTask.java:60)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I cannot provide the pdf document (client information), nor can I 'fix' the pdf (3rd party). Without me having to delve in iTextSharp source code, would I be so lucky that the above info would be enough for someone to modify iTextSharp to handle this issue (I suspect the document has a real issue, but it seems like iTextSharp could work around the issue just like pdfreader does?).

PDF bytes (66500 - 66600 => 103c4 - 10428; I just opened the pdf in ultra edit. Is the pdf compressed? Are the byte counts from the error message from the compressed stream or uncompressed?)

```
000103c0h: 06 A8 4E 51 B9 1A EC 18 21 D5 08 10 95 96 06 E6 ; .¨NQ¹.ì.!Õ..•–.æ
000103d0h: B9 65 30 30 B0 25 00 B9 40 0A 2A C4 96 01 11 49 ; ¹e00°%.¹@.*Ä–..I
000103e0h: 4B 83 CA 29 29 A9 65 40 9C 05 94 07 B3 81 A2 A1 ; KƒÊ))©e@œ.”.³¢¡
000103f0h: A1 78 3C 04 04 DA 0C 8C 71 91 40 5A 18 88 45 C1 ; ¡x<..Ú.Œq‘@Z.ˆEÁ
00010400h: 22 CA 0C 3C AC 1F 56 4A 27 B6 49 1B 70 71 4F D8 ; "Ê.<¬.VJ'¶I.pqOØ
00010410h: CB B4 E0 F8 D4 05 0C 52 0B F6 4B 14 EC 5D A6 6C ; Ë´àøÔ..R.öK.ì]¦l
00010420h: 74 F0 C2 61 C9 0D 10 EF EB 32 30 26 FC 05 D2 4C ; tðÂaÉ..ïë20&ü.ÒL
00010430h: 40 6C 0B C4 C6 0C 8C 05 67 40 F6 03 11 23 40 80 ; @l.ÄÆ.Œ.g@ö..#@€
```

Comment: As for *Invalid object number. at file pointer 66562* - Maybe you could extract the bytes around that offset, e.g. from 66500 till 66600?

Comment: I extracted the bytes - please let me know if I did this right...

Comment: You wanted to extract 103c4 - 10428 but you did extract 1030 - 104f...

Comment: Updated the bytes. Darn those ever-changing hex conventions. Whatever happened to the good old $ prefix.

Comment: Ok, there definitively is no object number at or even near to the index mentioned. Thus, any attempt to parse the document as a whole is likely to fail. Therefore, I'd propose you try opening the PDF using a constructor which does not read the whole file.  In itext (Java) that would mean using a RandomFileOrArray.

Comment: I had the same issue. It turned out that pdf was invalid - it had correct pdf file at the start and then some garbage after %%EOF (some intern opened file to write with OpenOrCreate flag).